# merge multiple $http into one to solve scope issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have multiple of below code; how can I combine all of them? since $scope.mydata or even global var mydata is not accessible outside of $http.

```
   $http({
    url: "php/mainLoad.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: {"userId":"1"}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.mydata = data;
        mydata = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // $scope.status = status;
       alert(status);
    });
```

Comment: Combine what? Can you clarify your question. Also more code will help.

Comment: @smk how do you do multiple load using $http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use promises. $http is a promise, like $q object. First inject $q, then do:

```
call1 = $http ({});
call2 = $http ({});
call3 = $http ({});

$q.all ([call1, call2, call3])
.then(function(response) {
    responseFromFirstCall = response[0];
    responseFromSecondCall = response[1];
    responseFromThirdCall = response[2];
}, function(errResponse) {
    firstErrorResponse = errResponse;
});
```

Function in `.then(function...` will fire only when all calls (promises) are resolved. If any of the calls is rejected, the second function will call, and the errResponse will be the response from first rejected call. This second parameter, ie. the second function, is optional.

Comment: It is quite hard to catch it at beginning but it is very handy... You can read about $q here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q. As I said before, $http is also an instance of $q with some other functionalities (however, replaceble), like .success and .error.